# Nullish coalescing operator (??) with right hand side 'undefined'

Tags: typescript

Is there ever a need to use Nullish coalescing operator (??) where the right hand is undefined? I feel the obvious answer is "No" since the result should always be undefined, but I wonder if anyone had any interesting usage.

```
const undefValue = undefined;
const useless = undefValue ?? undefined
```

Comment: *"the result should always be undefined"* - why do you think so?

Comment: Because you wouldn’t reach the right side of the code unless the left side of the ?? is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` and `undefined` continue to be sort of an annoying thing in javascript programming. When a type has both, this can help you wrangle that.

So because `null` and `undefined` both are considered falsy to the `??` operator, that means error:

```
const a: string | null | undefined = getSomeValue()
const b: string | undefined = a
// Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
//  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.(2322)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4&ts=4.5.0-beta&ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=70#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMQMBlHAWxADUoJkQAKASgC54BnDGLVA+AH3ipkECAPhpQiHiGAAoOWDyd4UNp269xw0eMkhpqWfAC8hYmUo06jJouUZ4AI3VcefQfsPGzUOQHp-eAAVAE8ABwQAcg13bRExT1QpGWAo+Cx2IRxHKHZ2LAJUKCcIBAwceAwI6NitJJSjNIA6AKCQmvgonQh0zOzc-MLi0vLK6siuuo8JZINUqOaGACYAZmXlpiA)

Could be fixed like this:

```
const b: string | undefined = a ?? undefined // works
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4&ts=4.5.0-beta&ssl=4&ssc=54&pln=4&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMQMBlHAWxADUoJkQAKASgC54BnDGLVA+AH3ipkECAPhpQiHiGAAoOWDyd4UNp269xw0eMkhpqWfAC8hYmUo06jJouUZ4AI3VcefQfsPGzUeAH5-CVQpGWB4AHoI+AB3HBgAa3YgA)

Or vice versa with:

```
const b: string | null = a ?? null // works
```

---

Another way to think of it is that `someUnion ?? something` returns a type where all the union members in the type of `someUnion` that are `null` or `undefined` are replaced with the type of `something`.

Maybe that replacement is `null` or `undefined`, and maybe it's something else entirely.